How do I make Linux wait for /dev/usb/lp0 to have successfully printed a page?
I have a Dell 2130cn USB PCL-XL printer, and I am making a JetDirect/port 9100 print server with filters (converts PostScript to PCL-XL, converts PNG, etc.) for it. I am mostly doing this to learn how printers work and how CUPS and print spoolers work from behind.
For context, I am trying to add bidirectional communication.
When I try to:
echo "Hello World!" > /dev/usb/lp0

It doesn't wait for the job to complete, and instead it instantly returns to the shell.
Expected outcome:
$ echo "Hello World!" > /dev/usb/lp0
[ wait until paper comes out of the printer, then returns to shell ]
$ _

Current outcome:
$ echo "Hello World!" > /dev/usb/lp0
[ returns to shell instantly, doesn't wait for the job to complete ]
$ _


Consider using CUPS

You can't; the line printer protocol really gives no appropriate form of feedback like that. In fact, many printers don't at all have a way of telling the computer that they're finished with a page; they can say things like "I'm ready to accept the next document to print", but that can happen long before the current job is finished printing.
Maybe, however, your printer does, through an interface that's not the simplistic line printer (lp means line printer, you know, these 1960s giant loud things that could print text line by line on endless paper, rather than pages?) interface. In that case, you'd want to set up your printer in CUPS, the standard print job manager on Linux; so when you send something for printing using CUPS's lpr, you can then do something like
timeout=61
while [[ timeout -gt 0 ]]; do
  lpstat -W completed -u \
  | grep -q $ID_GOTTEN_FROM_LPR && break
  timeout=$((timeout - 1))
done
[[ timeout -gt 0 ]] || echo "not finished in 60s!"
# continue

or such.
Again, it's not usual that printer correctly report they're done printing. Especially modern printers have memory for many documents and might tell you "yeah I'm done receiving the print job", and never report back when they were actually printing it, or even finished it.

I have once printed directly to a HP PhotoSmart printer and it did wait for the job to complete, but I am not sure if it was related to the OS or the printer. (can't test, the printer/computer isn't at home). Also for more information, it's a USB printer.

USB: that was clear from your device path, but you're still using it as if it was a 1960's line printer by simply putting text to its input interface

so, you're failing your own assignment "learning how printers work", by forcing your printer to work as if it was a device that has absolutely no resemblance to what it actually is, in emulation of devices that are 60 years old. You need to put in PCL as printing data, and you (probably, assuming your PCL printer supports that) need to use PJL to specify the print job and get completion information from it. To do that, you need a program that outlives the task of "sending data via USB to the device"; so, that's nothing you should be doing in a shell script. @0penrc

most importantly, you need a program that opens the link to the printer in a bidirectional way; the shell's > is not going to do that. You cannot "make Linux wait"; that's exactly the job of the software you are planning to write :)

I can try and poll the PJL INFO STATUS command, but I fear that it might not allow bidirectional communication. I am trying to allow both regular print drivers (requires bidirectional communication) and allow raw postscript to be sent (doesn't require bidirectional communication) Sorry if the post seems a bit confusing on what I am trying to do, english isn't my native language.

Ah, but your English is very nice! Anyways, if you need information from the printer, you must have bidirectional communications. So, that's a logical necessity. And the bidirectional connection would be between your daemon and the printer, not necessarily between a client and your daemon.

I am basically trying to make print drivers think it's directly communicating with the printer without any middleman. The main problem I am facing right now is the fact that print drivers try and communicate with the printer using PJL but fail because every command (socat, normal cat) talks with the printer instantly but it won't receive from it till I run another cat from the printer or use socat again.

yes, so your driver has to have a bidirectional communication channel to the printer to get information from the printer. That's the end of it. You cannot allow more than one program (i.e, your driver) to talk to the printer at any one time; so you need to fix your system design.
